# Both vertex-transitive and edge-transitive graph is bipartite.

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

My first question:

Let $G$ be a graph that is both vertex-transitive (Then $G$ is regular of degree k, *say.*) and edge-transitive , prove that $G$ is bipartite and its simple eigenvalue is $k$ and $-k$.

Another question: if $G$ only has simple eigenvalue  , prove that $G$ has at most two vertices.

---

I find that a triangle  is vertex-transitive and edge-transitive ,but it's not bipartite. So how can I correct the first problem? For the second problem, a simple eigenvalue $\theta$ must satisfy $\theta\equiv k\; (\mod\;2)$. Since $G$ is $k-$regular, $|\theta|\leq k$. If $G$ is a simple graph ,then the problem is done, but if $G$ is not simple ,how can I solve it ? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I expect the first question is incorrect, probably it should say that if the graph is edge-transitive but NOT vertex-transitive then it is bipartite.

Comment: But I guess the simple eigenvalue of $G$ must be $k$ and $-k$. Can we prove it?